# java script code for required field validator

Tags: asp.net

Please suggest me how to write the java scripting code to specify a required field validator for a text box with out using the inbuilt required validator feature in asp.net

Comment: Best Source : http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-sample-registration-form-validation.php

Comment: Your question misses most of the important part needed to answer it properly. What do you want to archieve? What have you tried? What didn't work as expected and why? Where did you look? What's wrong with what you found?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
function ValidateInput() {
            var validationMessage = "Your Txt is not valid";
            var isValid = true;
            if (document.getElementById('<%= txt.ClientID %>').value = '') {
                    // update the message
                    isValid = false;
                }
            if (!isValid)
                alert(validationMessage);
            return false;
        }
```